# Navigate in cached Flutter Engine

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-android, flutter-engine

I have a question regarding **FlutterEngine**
I have a single cached flutter engine that I wanna reuse on many screens in my android app, so I'd have to somehow navigate the routes inside cached engine.

*Is there any way I can set the route of cached engine before starting the flutter activity?*

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

After some research and diving into documentation, I found out that flutter engine provides a [`NavigationChannel`](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/index.html?io/flutter/embedding/engine/systemchannels/NavigationChannel.html) that can be used to push/pop routes into an engine

Example, if you want to push a route:

```
FlutterEngine engine = FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().get("MyFlutterEngine");
if (engine != null) {
    engine.getNavigationChannel().pushRoute("/myRoute2");
}
```

Comment: I've followed the same but not working. any workaround?